# XML Parsing Error on WCF

Tags: c#, xml, wcf

When I get start to running `WCF` service.
error message when access `.svc`

[image]

**HotelService.scv**

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="HotelService.Hotel" %>
```

**web.Config**

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
</appSettings>
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
</system.web>

<!-- Service Model-->
<system.serviceModel>

  <bindings>
    <wsHttpBinding>
      <binding name="wsHttp" messageEncoding="Mtom"
               maxReceivedMessageSize="1000000000">
        <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="1000000000"/>
        <security mode="None"/>
      </binding>
    </wsHttpBinding>
  </bindings>

  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="mexBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>

  <services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="mexBehavior"
             name="HotelService.Hotel">
      <endpoint address="http://localhost/HotelService/HotelService.svc"
                binding="wsHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="wsHttp"
                contract="HotelService.IHotel" />
      <host>
        <baseAddresses>
          <add baseAddress="http://localhost"/>
        </baseAddresses>
      </host>
    </service>
  </services>

</system.serviceModel>

<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  <!--
      To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
      Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
    -->
  <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Is there any error in your web service?

Comment: if i running on laptop web service works, but on my pc computer nothing show error message.

Comment: if i running on laptop web service works, but on my pc computer nothing show error message. 
whether this difference in Windows 10 and Windows 8.1 is not compatible? because WCF Service in windows 10 .NET 4.6 and in Windows 8.1 .NET 4.5